How to dynamically register services with ServiceProvider in .net maui blazor hybrid
I want to create a plugin system in my .net Maui Blazor hybrid app, which leads me to the problem of creating a new ServiceProvider and using it instead of the default one. How to inform Blazor to use only newly created ServiceProvider?
I created a ServiceLocator class which keeps information about current ServiceProvider and already registered services
public static class ServiceLocator
{
     public static IServiceProvider ServiceProvider { get; set; }
     public static IServiceCollection Services { get; set; } = new ServiceCollection();
}

public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
{
    var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
    builder
        .UseMauiApp<App>()
        .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
        {
            fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
        });

    // Register services
    builder.Services.AddScoped<IPluginInstaller, PluginInstaller>();
    // Register other servieces...

    // Save already registered services
    foreach (var service in builder.Services)
    {
        ServiceLocator.Services.Add(service);
    }

    var app = builder.Build();
    ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider = app.Services;

    return app;
}

and
public interface IPluginInstaller
{
    void InstallPlugin();
}

public class PluginInstaller : IPluginInstaller
{
    public void InstallPlugin()
    {
        // Create new ServiceCollection
        var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();

        // Add services to new newly created collection
        foreach(var service in ServiceLocator.Services)
        {
              serviceCollection.Add(services);
        }

        var plugin = new Plugin(...)

        serviceCollection.AddSingleton(plugin);
        serviceCollection.AddScoped<IService_A, Service_A>();
        serviceCollection.AddScoped<IService_B, Service_B>();

        // Create new ServiceProvider
        var newServiceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

        // Assign reference of newly created ServiceProvider
        ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider = newServiceProvider;
    }
}

Finally, in Main.razor I have the following code:
@page "/"
@inject IEumerbale<Plugin> Plugins
@inject IPluginInstaller PluginInstaller

@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        PluginInstaller.InstallPlugin();
        var counter = Plugins.Count() // gives 0
    }
}

It seems to me, like injecting IPluginInstaller keeps the default Dependency Container still alive, hence blazor is not automatically using newly created as the refernce is still in use (with @inject IPluginInstaller) depespite ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider = newServiceProvider; If I GetService from ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider it sees the added plugins.
Do you know how to solve these issues? Maybe the approach needs to be changed dramatically..

Did you mean that you want to disable the default container and use the one you create?

Yes, exactly, however Blazor prevents me from this, as I suppose it still uses reference of the old one

Yes, there is no way to change or disable the default container (app.Services and builder.Services can't be set). Unless you give up the maui self-contained dependency injection.

I'm implementing Autofac approach right now which handles dynamic container update. Hopefully, this will help

@LiyunZhang-MSFT, can explain what you mean by give up the maui self-contained dependency injection? Can you tell how to implement this?

What I mean is if you want to achiece this, you may need to use 3rd party dependency injection.
